# How to make thumbnail images click into blog posts

Tags: post-thumbnails

How do I make it so the thumbnails in the list of blog posts on my blog are clickable, so that when the user clicks the thumbnail image, the blog post opens up?

If it helps, this is the blog: http://wordfruit.com/blog

Comment: Richard,
Can you paste the code from your index.php or themes home page template file? That would allow us to give you the best answer.

Answer (score 2):

Do you want to make all the thumbnails link to their respective blog posts?  If so, use the following code in the `functions.php` file:

```
add_filter( 'post_thumbnail_html', 'my_post_image_html', 10, 3 );
function my_post_image_html( $html, $post_id, $post_image_id ) {
    $html = '<a href="' . get_permalink( $post_id ) . '" title="' . 
        esc_attr( get_post_field( 'post_title', $post_id ) ) . '">' . $html . '</a>';
    return $html;
}
```

If you only want the post thumbnails to link to the post permalink in a specific loop, use the following code in the query like Jamal mentioned earlier:

```
if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) : 
    ?><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>" ><?php 
        the_post_thumbnail(); 
    ?></a><?php 
endif;
```

The loop is in the `index.php` page. Take a look at the WordPress Codex regarding [The Loop](http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop) and you can see where pieces of the code should fall depending on your theme.

Answer (score 1):

You need to edit your theme's `index.php` and category, tag, etc archives to enable this. If you're comfortable in editing your theme's files, then you can replace the code that calls post thumbnails with the following one:

```
<?php 
    /* Display the thumbnail only when available. */
    if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) : 
?>
        <a title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
            <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
        </a>
<?php 
    /* Remember that we had a conditional check open; close it. */
    endif; 
?>
```

Comment: Thanks Jamàl. What is the code that I delete and replace with this code? (the code that calls post thumbnails)

Comment: @Richard, yes. You need to replace the code that calls the post thumbnails. But be careful when you're doing this. You may break your website if you are not comfortable in editing codes.

Comment: Hi Jamàl -- I mean what is that code? -- I don't know which bit of code I need to select and delete...

Answer (score 0):

```
if ( function_exists( 'add_theme_support' ) ) { 
  add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' ); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks Mohit. I guess I'll try this if the other one doesn't work. I'm not sure which style.css I should add this to -- I have a style.css called 'twentyeleven' and one called 'wordfruit' -- do you know which it's most likely to be? Also, where do I add this code in the file?

Comment: post this in functions.php

Comment: Hi Mohit; I put that code in functions.php -- the thumbnails are still not clickable -- maybe I put the code in the wrong place in the file -- is there a particular place in functions.php where I should paste the code?

Comment: Also, in the folder 'themes', I have 3 folders: 'twentyeleven' / 'twentyten' / 'wordfruit' -- each has a 'functions.php' file -- which one should I be editing?

Comment: well functions.php of you theme root folder and there is no sequel paste it anywhere in functions.php but not between any other function well here is your solution for clickable thumbnail check this link well there is code where is loop you must add this in single.php according to your theme style http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_post_thumbnail

Answer (score 0):

paste this into your functions.php file. It will make the images in your post go to the post instead of image source.

```
function wpguy_linked_image($content){

    $searchfor = '/(<img[^>]*\/>)/';
    $replacewith = '<a href="'.get_permalink().'">$1</a>';

    if (is_single() === FALSE){
        $content = preg_replace($searchfor, $replacewith, $content, 1);
    }
    return $content;

}

add_filter('the_content', 'wpguy_linked_image');
```

Comment: This is a rather old question, but an answer can be useful for people visiting this question page nonetheless. However, you only provide code. Please include an explanation for what the code does *and* provide comments in the code.