# Which is the child theme and which is the parent theme?

Tags: child-theme, parent-theme

In the themes folder for my blog, there are three folders and one file:

The file is index.php and the folders are: twentyeleven / wordfruit / twentyten

The blog is at http://wordfruit.com/blog

Obviously folders could be given any label, but I think the folders are organised fairly logically.

Question 1:
Is 'twentyeleven' likely the child theme and 'wordfruit' likely the parent theme?

Question 2:
I want to edit a file so that when a user clicks a thumbnail image in the list of blog posts, the blog post opens up...

(As per this post: [How to make thumbnail images click into blog posts](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/30542/how-to-make-thumbnail-images-click-into-blog-posts) )

As I understand, I need to edit the index.php file...

Do I edit the index.php in the child theme or the parent theme?

Comment: You have to edit the index.php of wordfruit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your site is not using a Child Theme.

It is currently using the **WordFruit** Theme, and this Theme [**does not declare any Theme as a *Template***](http://wordfruit.com/blog/wp-content/themes/wordfruit/style.css). If it *were*, you would see a **`Template: parent-theme`** header tag (where "parent-theme" would be, e.g. `twentyeleven` if it were using Twenty Eleven as its parent Theme) in style.css

Thus, WordFruit appears to be a **stand-alone** Theme.

So, if you want to make changes to WordFruit, you would need to make changes to the Theme directly, or create a Child Theme that uses Wordfruit as its template (Parent Theme).

Comment: Now that I've been using Childtheme's more I would suggest making a Childtheme or WordFruit and making your changes there.